# How to stop method from executing with code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in my controller which I call with ajax.
The method can be called VERY often (depends on the speed of typing of the user).
The user types letters, words. I want the method to be called once the user stops typing.

The parameter of the method is the written text by the user.

In my way, the method gets called a lot of times in a small amount of time.

Is there a way to call the method always (after each letter) but then the method to stop executing immediately if it is called right away?

Example: a user will write slowly 10 letters - the method will be called 10 times.
Example: a user will write fast 10 letters - the method will be called the 10th time OR the method will get called 10 times but will stop executing the first 9 times and finish executing only the 10th time

Comment: do you use jQuery for the ajax call?

Comment: Are you implementing an "autocomplete" manually? Maybe you can check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Even if you're not implementing an autocomplete, that autocomplete does implement `do nothing until the user pauses typing` behaviour that you might be able to learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that using javascript timers. Here's an example that triggers any logic once it has been half a second since the user's last keypress.
If the user keeps typing then the timers are constantly being cancelled:

```
$(function() {
    var timer;
    $(".typeAhead").keypress(function() {
        if (timer != null)
            clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            // do ajax call
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

This snippet uses jquery, but you can do it without it. Just use `getElementById()` instead of the selectors.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are calling it with AJAX then I think you'd be better placing the logic client-side.  Consider using something like [throttle.js](http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/) which only posts the Ajax calls after a pause in typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by buffering results & passing them into this method. Basically, by wrapping this method in an aggregator method you can prevent this from firing all the time.

```
//... Class Impl

private string keys = String.Empty;
private readonly TimeSpan bufferDelay = new TimeSpan(100000);
private DateTime lastKeyPress = DateTime.UtcNow;

private void DoSomething(string text)
{
//do something to process text.
    keys = String.Empty;

}


public void DoSomethingBuffer(string text)
{
    keys =+ text;
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    if((now-lastKeyPress) > bufferDelay)
{
    DoSomething(keys);
}
    lastKeyPress = now;

}
//... More Class Impl
```

You'll need to play with the aggregation time window to find somethign that feels natural, but it should be relatively simple. You'll call DoSOmethingBuffer rather than DoSomethign directly.